# can't find text box element by xpath or css selector

Tags: python, selenium, input, textbox, element

I am trying to enter some text into a text box on a webpage, here is the screenshot [screenshot for Enter Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isgu4.png).

My code works fine for all other elements except for the highlighted text box in the screenshot:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content-column"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div[2]/input'))).send_keys("aapl")
```

It doesn't look like in a frame or iframe. Please see the source code for the website:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Add a symbol..." class="sec-search-box bc-form__add-symbol-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched placeholder" data-ng-model="userEnteredSymbols" data-barchart-clear-input="" required="">
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can input the value using the xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-ng-model='userEnteredSymbols']"))).send_keys("aapl")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Absolute xpath` which is not a recommended way. You can try with below `xpath` with `webdriver wait`

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-ng-model= 'userEnteredSymbols']")))
element.send_keys("aapl")
```

you need below import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```